# What is this snake in South Florida, USA

Tags: species-identification, zoology, herpetology, snake

I observed this snake for about 10 minutes. It was slithering back and forth in about 50x20 yard (50x20 meter) area. Just kept going back and forth (then I left). There was a similar snake at the same time in roughly the same 50x20 area, but they didn't seem to be paying attention to each other.

This is in South Florida, near Naples, Florida, USA.[image]
I took several pictures, but I think this one is the clearest.

Comment: Google helped me find [this site](https://www.floridamuseum.ufl.edu/florida-snake-id/?_sft_snake_pattern=uniform&_sft_snake_color=black). Using this tool, it might be a North American Racer, but I'm not positive.  It'd help if you had pics of its underbelly color or scale texture

Comment: @Punintended - I think I see a white throat. I agree it's a racer. Your guess is probably correct.

Comment: Thank you. Any idea what it was doing, running around back and forth?

Comment: Laps?  IDK, it is a Racer